# Visual Studio 2008 C Drop down menu assist?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

Is there an option to enable the drop down menu that appears when coding in other languages such as html/vb/ect for C in Visual Studio?

Comment: If you set up your project workspace properly it will work I believe.. its not working? or you have not created a workspace?

Comment: I do mean the autocomplete box. I did not setup a workspace? I just made a blank C++ project and then added my c files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press Ctrl+Space to produce this menu. For example, after typing "pri", press Ctrl+Space, if you're looking for printf().